# Как передать путь в метод?

Tags: c#

```
public partial class clearTools : Form
{

    static clearTools instance = null;
    public clearTools()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instance = this;

    }
    
    static void MonitorDesktop(string path)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileWatcher.Path = path;
        fileWatcher.Created += onDesktop;
        fileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

     static void onDesktop(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
        Console.WriteLine(fi.Extension);
        if (fi.Extension == ".txt")
        {
            File.Move(e.FullPath, @$"{instance.imgPath.Text}\{e.Name}");

        }
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
        MonitorDesktop(desktopPath);
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113944/discussion-on-question-by-viannedi-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
static void onDesktop(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
    Console.WriteLine(fi.Extension);
    if (fi.Extension == ".txt")
    {
        string path = "";
        instance.Invoke((Action)(() => path = instance.imgPath.Text));
        File.Move(e.FullPath, @$"{path}\{e.Name}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: случайно убрал, вернул обратно